# notation for the set n choose k

Tags: combinatorics, notation

Lately I've found myself writing things like $ijk \in {n \choose 3}$, by which I mean that $i,j,k$ are coming from the sets *enumerated* by ${n \choose 3 }$. It's a slight abuse of notation, since ${ n \choose 3 }$ is usually understood to be a number and not the set it is counting.

Is there a standard notation for this set? i.e. the set of cardinality $k$ subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$.

I'd be happy to learn that the answer is no and that my abuse of notation is common or clear enough.

Comment: I sometimes see the notation $[k]$ where $k$ is a natural number for the set $\{1, \dots, k\} $.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given a set $X$, we have the notation for the set of size-$k$ subsets of $X$:

$$\binom{X}{k} := \{A~:~|A|=k,~A\subseteq X\}$$

Further, the set $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ can be notated as $[n]$.  There are some authors who prefer to have this represent instead $\{0,1,2,3,\dots,n-1\}$.  In either event, $[n]$ is the prototypical $n$-element set of the first $n$ natural numbers and most scenarios where you see $[n]$ it doesn't actually matter which interpretation it was since the end result of whatever was being talked about winds up being the same.

So, a particular three-element subset $\{i,j,k\}$ of $\{1,2,3,\dots,n\}$ can be written as

$$\{i,j,k\}\in\binom{[n]}{3}$$

Comment: For reference, see for example chapter 1 of Stanley's Enumerative Combinatorics.

Comment: Accepting this answer because of the comment, which is more or less what I was after. (Not an explanation of what the set meant.)

Answer (score 2):

Use $A\choose k$ where $A$ is a set, like $\{1,\ldots,n\}\choose k$.
This makes sense, since

$\left\vert {\{1,\ldots,n\}\choose k}\right\vert = {n\choose k}$.